# Are netscape email addresses still valid?

Tags: email-address

I am trying to contact a person which employer organisation states can be reached at `<name>@netscape.net`. I have sent an email to this address from my gmail account a few hours ago, and so far have not received the standard message one gets if the address does not exist:

```
The original message was received at Fri, 31 Feb 2017 09:50:59 -0400 (EDT)
from mx0b-00256a01.pphosted.com [67.231.153.242]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<name>@netscape.net (reason: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try)

etc...
```

I know nowadays you can set up email accounts of the like `name@whatever.example`. However, this person is an old academic (80+), now retired, and I get the impression that email might have been valid at a time when netscape was still around.

How can I know if I have the sightest chance of getting a reply? Is there anything I can do to test through a different mean if an email address is still valid?

---

## Update:

I got a reply - he answered! Amazing!

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about running your own website or setting up email for your domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I came here because of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279386/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-email).

Comment: Setting up a custom domain email as per that question is on-topic.    We don't accept questions here unless they are related to your site or domain.

Comment: I've added another answer with more detail to that post.

Answer (score 3):

There’s still an MX DNS record for netscape.net, which points to an AOL/Yahoo mail server, so your email should be going *somewhere*.

Comment: Thanks! How do you know this? Can you add some links or reference? (not that I don't believe you, but I want to learn about it).

Comment: try this https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3anetscape.net&run=toolpage